# Uncaught ReferenceError: stopme is not defined (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, setinterval

I keep seeing this non breaking exception in my console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: stopme is not defined
```

(anonymous function)

There is no variable called stopme being called in any of my files, did a full search in console. What I have are multiple:

```
setInterval(function() {
  updateMetrics();
}, 1000);
```

calls in my code, whenever one of them fails, this shows up in console. I also don't know if this is the default behavior but I also noticed every time I set a new interval using:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {}, 1000);
```

that intervalId is non sequential as in:`console.log(intervalId)` the result is `1, 4, 9, 14`. I am manually calling the code above from console to see why my intervalIds are auto incrementing.

This is the full stack trace:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: stopme is not defined
(anonymous function)
```

Additional libraries:

```
bootstrap.js
d3.v3.js
ember.js
handlebars.js
jquery-1.9.1.js
jquery.jsPlumb.js
jquery.timeago.js
require.js
string.min.js
```

Error shows up only on Chrome, not in Firefox. My Chrome build is: Version 29.0.1547.57

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace? This happen when the application loads, or when you make a transition to a route?

Comment: also useful to know is what other js libraries you are using if any?

Comment: It's a silly suggestion, but search for "stopme" in all your .js files. Who knows, it maybe being used by a third-party script. Also hammer Ctrl + Shift + R a few times to clear the cache.

Comment: I've just seen this exact same error in the wild from our web app's window.onerror reporting.  We don't have any 'stopme' occurring in our JavaScript code, and we don't use Emberjs.  User agent was also Chrome/29.0.1547.57.  Could it be a Chrome extension you have installed?  We could compare 'navigator.plugins'?

Comment: Are you using Google Analytics?  Or any of the related analytic softwares?  that code looks familiar

Comment: I also think it's an extension.. I"m getting the same problem over here.. It's only happening in chrome. Here are my extensions:

http://www.otleylogic.com/screenshots/Screen%20Shot%202013-08-27%20at%2012.54.35%20AM-wxrgOYobHO.png

http://www.otleylogic.com/screenshots/Screen%20Shot%202013-08-27%20at%2012.54.52%20AM-qb738v6OvZ.png

Comment: @jake is right, I searched through all my code and couldn't find it, this is not an ember issue, this is because of the Webpage Screenshot Capture extension.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I tracked this to my "Webpage Screenshot Capture" extension. Sucks because it's a great extension for capturing full height web pages. Can anyone recommend another?

Comment: Yep, I can confirm the issue is with the "Webpage Screenshot Capture" extension. @Rohit, can you mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: This is right, the only solution I found was to disable the extension. I am using "Awesome Screenshot: Capture & Annotate" instead now: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce?

Comment: Thanks!!! I was already blaming the commercial running on our sites. For once it's my own plugin.

Comment: It will be fixed today. Sorry for that

Comment: Fixed in Webpage Screenshot v12.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to "Webpage Screenshot Capture" chrome extension. After disabling it the bug is gone.

The bug has been appeared when navigating through pages in backbonejs application.

Comment: Fixed in version Webpage Screenshot v12.

Answer (score 0):

+1. I also met this issue. And finally I found only one of my end user will occur this error. Searched it for google, that said extension's error will trigger `window.onerror`.